# How do I merge these two bits of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm putting together a Flask web app as a final project for a course, and I'm struggling to fix some JavaScript for the site's registration form.

I have two independent bits of code, one from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) to validate form completeness:

```
    <script>

    (function()
    {
      'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function()
      {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form)
        {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event)
          {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false)
            {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }

            form.classList.add('was-validated');

          }, false);
        });
      }, false);
    })();

    </script>
```

and one that I customized to check that the user is registering a unique username. If the username is not unique, it populates an innerHTML error to a "user_result" div tag beneath the username form field:

```
<script>
        // set input value to form entry for username
        let input = document.getElementById('user');

        // on key up, run check
        input.onkeyup = function()
        {
            // query to check username against database
            $.get('/check?username=' + input.value, function(data)
            {
                // if check query returns False, username is NOT available
                if (!data)
                {
                    // put notification text into result tag above
                    document.getElementById('user_result').innerHTML = 'Username unavailable.';

                    // prevent form submission via register button
                    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener("click", function(event)
                    {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
                // if check query returns True, username is available
                if (data)
                {
                    // no notification text required
                    document.getElementById('user_result').innerHTML = '';

                    // allow form submission by unbinding event handler
                    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener("click", function(event)
                    {
                        event.unbind();
                    });
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Individually, each seems to work okay, but:

1. I can't seem to put both scripts in the same HTML doc without unexpected behavior (e.g. the form won't submit, but no error messages show, or the form submits despite a bad username.)
2. I'd really like for the "Username unavailable." message to display in the same style of the "invalid-feedback" class used for the Bootstrap form validation.

I'd even be fine checking for the username availability upon submit (see below attempt) instead of upon keyup, but I'd ideally check username validity before form submission.

Here is one of my attempts to stitch the code pieces together. The result here unfortunately is that the Bootstrap validation works, but the username check is ignored (I can submit the form with a bad username and instead of the JS blocking the form submission, it goes through).

```
    <script>

    (function()
    {
      // set input value to form entry for username
      let input = document.getElementById('user');

      'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function()
      {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form)
        {

          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event)
          {
            if (form.checkValidity() === true)
            {
            (function()
            {
            $.get('/check?username=' + input.value, function(data)
            {
                // if check query returns False, username is NOT available
                if (!data)
                {
                    // put notification text into result tag above
                    document.getElementById('user_result').innerHTML = 'Username unavailable.';

                    // prevent form submission via register button
                    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener("click", function(event)
                    {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });
                }
                // if check query returns True, username is available
                if (data)
                {
                    // no notification text required
                    document.getElementById('user_result').innerHTML = '';

                    // allow form submission by unbinding event handler
                    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener("click", function(event)
                    {
                        event.unbind();
                        event.stopPropogation();
                    });
                }
            });
            });
            }

            if (form.checkValidity() === false)
            {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }

            form.classList.add('was-validated');

          }, false);
        });
      }, false);
    })();

    </script>
```

Can someone help me understand where my thinking is wrong?  Please let me know if it'd be helpful to see the HTML form or Flask code for the username check.

Comment: What have you tried to fix the issue so far?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your structure? I can see two script tags, which makes me think you load them in your HTML. Can you split up this JS into your static folder?

Comment: You're right that the script tags were included at the bottom of the HTML -- I'll try to save a separate file.  Would this typically be handled as two independent JS files if responding to different events or is combining logic the better approach? Thanks!

Comment: Is it mandatory for your project to validate forms only on the javascript side?

Not being a great javascript specialist myself, I can show you how to do this quite simply on the Flask side.